# Screen brightness fading options

Tags: 11.04, screen

I am using Ubuntu Natty on my laptop. While unplugged screen fades out, gets a little bit darker. It is great for the battery.

The question is how I can adjust the time before the fades out. Now it is something like 5 seconds.

When I read I must hold my finger on the touchpad in order to be not annoying of the brightness shifts every time.

1 or 5 minutes should be better.

I looked for it in Compiz configuration with no success....

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be configurable using the gconf-editor:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gconf-editor` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. In the gconf-editor find the key

   `/apps/gnome-power-manager/backlight/idle_dim_time`

   and set it to the desired value (in seconds):

   [image]

Comment: Great. Thank you very much! it was just the thing I needed! Love Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

[Update for Oneiric - 11.10]

I couldn't find the setting mentioned by htorque in Oneiric.

Instead, in the "Screen" settings (open the dashboard, type "Screen", select the "Screen" application), there is a "Dim screen to save power" checkbox.

[image: Screen Settings]

Uncheck it, and the screen won't fade out anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In Oneiric you need to use dconf-editor: 
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-time [set to whatever you want]

It seems like it would be easy to create an interface that enables users to set all this stuff. I don't like how Oneiric has all the config UIs spread out in little pieces now. It makes more sense to have a unified UI for power management with all the settings that most users are going to want to change. Definitely a step backwards.

Without a good set of default config UIs you get what we've always had on Linux: a bunch of overlapping config tools that help unwitting users fubar their systems.